# How to calculate a triad census for an undirected, weighted graph

Tags: r, igraph, sna, statnet

I would like to calculate a triad census of an undirected, weighted edgelist in R (using sna, igraph and statnet packages). `gdrkz` is an object of class `igraph`.

When using the following command:

```
triad.census(gdrkz, g=NULL, mode = c("graph"))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in triad.census(gdrkz, g = NULL, mode = c("graph")) : 
  unused arguments (gdrkz, mode = c("graph"))
```

When I try:

```
triad.census(gdrkz, mode = c("graph"))
```

I get the message:

```
Error in triad.census(gdrkz, mode = c("graph")) : 
  unused argument (mode = c("graph"))
```

The following command seems to work:

```
triad.census(gdrkz)
```

with the result:

```
29394     0  2427     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   672     0     0     0     0    16
```

But I get a warning message:

```
In triad.census(gdrkz) :
  At motifs.c:1052 :Triad census called on an undirected graph
```

Can I treat this output nonetheless like a normal result from a triad census for undirected graphs (by interpreting reciprocal dyads just as connected, undirected ones and ignoring all the surplus combinations that are not possible in an undirected graph)?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I have solved the problem:

I should have written:

sna::triad.census(gdrkz, g=NULL, mode = c("graph"))

which returns four values:

248635 10570 925 0

Sorry, I'm a beginner :)

Comment: You have to notice that the order in which the packages are loaded matters. Both `sna` and `igraph` have a function with the name `triad.census`, and whichever package was loaded last will be the default method that R uses. Using the double colon helps to disambiguate the call, that's why this works. HIH